# Como pegar o link de uma aba especifica bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma pagina que utilizo as Tabs navs do bootstrap 4.1,
Estou procurando e não encontro uma solução,
Quero fazer com que ao clicar em um link ele abrir uma 'aba' especifica do bootstrap.
Nesse exemplo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#">Profile</a>
<br />
<br />
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Perfil</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">Contato</div>
</div>
```

ao clicar no link `<a href="#">Profile</a>` ele ir para a aba Profile.
Pois quero fazer um redirect para uma determinada URL com PHP,
`index.php?id=2#nav-profile`, porém se eu chamar direto assim ele não vai para essa segunda aba e sim fica na primeira #home.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('nav-profile-tab').click()">Profile</a>
```

Não estou certo se existe uma opção com HTML puro, isso é uma saída com JavaScript.

Comment: Entendi, para o caso do link com o href bacana, como sugere que eu possa fazer isso como link de redirect no PHP?
Exemplo que citei: `index.php?id=2#nav-profile`